# How to add new field and update existing field simultaneously in cloud firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new field in a document but the field doesn't exist and update the existing field simultaneously, I tried using update and set both but none of them adds a new field although it works to update the existing field.

```
const userDocumentReference = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data['uid']);
    await userDocumentReference.update({
      'isVerified': 'pending', // old field
      'selfieUrl': data['selfieUrl'] // new field
    }, { merge: true });
```

Comment: Hello, how can you add a new field in a document **that doesn't exist** and update the existing field simultaneously? Where is the existing field, if the document does not exist? Please clarify. Note also that the `merge`option is to be use with set(), not `update()`.

Comment: Hi, I mean that field doesn't exist but the document does.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification and update! Using the `update()`method should definitely work. What is exactly `data['selfieUrl']`? Do you get any error with your existing code?

Comment: Hi, after removing `merge: true` it is working. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also, is it okay to store long generated image URLs in documents or it slows down the performance?

Comment: Do you mean storing in a Firestore Document a long string that is an URL?

Comment: Yes after uploading the image to firebase storage, as it does indexing behind the scenes.

Comment: If you are not going over the limits for a document or a field, there should no problem at all. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an existing Firestore document, using the [`update()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update) method, as follows should work:

```
const userDocumentReference = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data['uid']);

await userDocumentReference.update({
      'isVerified': 'pending', // old field
      'selfieUrl': data['selfieUrl'] // new field
    });
```